# Need help recreating crazy colors/material from example

Tags: materials

I found this three.js website that has a somewhat whacky color scheme that I really like: http://one-billion-cat.com/test/galerie/scene.html

Here it is as a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4e6yFQgu6U

I'm trying to find a material in blender that could give me this kind of look, but I'm not getting anywhere, so I thought maybe one of you guys might have an idea of how to go about achieving this.

I'd really appreciate some help with this, thanks folks =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is shader doing same result.

[image]

[image: screenshot - shader]

ADD:

Same result for Blender internal engine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: wow, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Do you know of a setup like this for the internal blender render engine? I want to export the scene with the blend4web addon, and this only supports the internal engine.. Thanks man =)

Comment: Look another file, man.

Answer (score 2):

If blend4web supports vertex colours you can bake normals to a Vertex Color map,

[image]

For the bake to work you must be in *Vertex Paint* mode, you don't need to create a UV map.

that will give you this effect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It very easy to create using blend4web. You don't need to bake this to vertex color (but blend4web really support it), you just need to connect Normal from the Geometry node to the Output in node material - Blend4web have full support of blender internal (not cycles) material nodes.